# How to go to last column of a table in jqgrid? without scrolling to the end

Tags: scroll, jqgrid

In many websites, when we scroll down a button would appear. It says 'Top'. when we click it, then it will take us to the top of the page.

My question is:
I want to have similar functionality in a table but horizontally.
Let me explain, I have a table in my application which has 100+ columns. So if I want to go to the last column, then I have to scroll horizontally till i reach last column. I am using **Jqgrid**. Is there any implementation in jqgrid which will take us to the last column just by clicking a button or something? Anyone tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/38/

[image]

Add a custom button to your jqgrid as shown in the fiddler, get the width of the 'ui-jqgrid-bdiv' class and scoll to right on the button click event,

```
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#sg1' + "_toppager", {
        caption: "See last column",
        title: "Last Column",
        onClickButton: function () {
            $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').animate({
                scrollLeft: $(this).width()
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: In general the idea is correct, but one should do small changes:  `$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv')` should be replaced to `$(this).closest('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv')` to prevent scrolling of *all* grids on the page. One should make some common things in the demo (independent from the main question): create grid using `data: mydata` instead of filling it by calling `addRowData` in the loop, remove unneeded `loadonce: true` and `index` properties , use numeric values for `height` and `width`, remove duplicate `id: "2"` data. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/99x50s2s/40/

Comment: Sure, will definitely follow these suggestions in the demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it really is helpful.. now my grid is easy to operate... :)